# What is a combinatorial embedding?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, topology, embeddings, topological-graph-theory

I got a reviewer comment saying  that I should consider using combinatorial embeddings rather than idk what I should call what I was doing topological embeddings?.

But I'm confused  because as far as I can see here [Combinatorial embedding of a graph](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12606/combinatorial-embedding-of-a-graph)
there is no difference between topological embeddings and combinatorial embeddings.